# can not upload larger files

Tags: php, upload, web-hosting, bluehost

hello all i am having a dedicated server and even after increasing the max_upload size and memory limit i can not upload videos of larger size please check the image [image]

i have a dedicated server from bluehost and the site is like video hosting site so i need to allow almost all file sizes but till now i have alloed max_file size arround 900 mbs but i can not upload files more than 10-20 mb please let me know if there is anything that i should do on my behalf.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, PHP permits a maximum file upload of 2MB. You can ask users to resize their images before uploading but let’s face it: they won’t. Fortunately, we can increase the limit when necessary.

Two PHP configuration options control the maximum upload size: upload_max_filesize and post_max_size. Both can be set to, say, “10M” for 10 megabyte file sizes.

However, you also need to consider the time it takes to complete an upload. PHP scripts normally time-out after 30 seconds, but a 10MB file would take at least 3 minutes to upload on a healthy broadband connection (remember that upload speeds are typically five times slower than download speeds). In addition, manipulating or saving an uploaded image may also cause script time-outs. We therefore need to set PHP’s max_input_time and max_execution_time to something like 300 (5 minutes specified in seconds).

These options can be set in your server’s php.ini configuration file so that they apply to all your applications. Alternatively, if you’re using Apache, you can configure the settings in your application’s .htaccess file:

php_value upload_max_filesize 10M

php_value post_max_size 10M

php_value max_input_time 300

php_value max_execution_time 300

Comment: can you tell me exactly what do i have to write in my htaccess file to increase all limits

Comment: you can define the constraints within your PHP application:
ini_set('upload_max_filesize', '10M');

ini_set('post_max_size', '10M');

ini_set('max_input_time', 300);
ini_set('max_execution_time', 300);
PHP also provides a set_time_limit() function so you don’t need to set max_execution_time directly.

Setting the options in your PHP code is possibly more practical, since you can extend the execution time and increase the file size when your application is expecting a large upload. Other forms would revert to the default 30-second time-out and 2MB limit.

Comment: The upload process doesn't get counted into the PHP execution time.

Comment: As long as the request isn't handed from the webserver to PHP, the execution time isn't going to start to count. And as long as you upload, the request is still holded by the webserver.